# Get the items in descending order using caml query

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query

i am trying to get the comments from Comment List in a '**Descending**' order , the query that i am using is :

```
"<Where>" +
  "<Eq>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='TopicID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ProjectID + "</Value>" +
  "</Eq>" +
  " <OrderBy>"+
    "<FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' />"+
  " </OrderBy>"+  
"</Where>";
```

but this query gives me the result in '**Ascending**' order even if i set it to false. what is wrong here?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment - the formatting in you question didn't make me notice the wrong nesting of the tags.

Comment: you could also write it this way to avoid concatenation: $@"<Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='TopicID' /><Value Type='Text'>{ProjectID}</Value> </Eq> </Where> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /> </OrderBy>"; The '$' is for the Params.
The '@' is to replace concatenation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`OrderBy` should be outside of the `Where` clause. Try modifying your query to this:

```
"<Where>" +
 "<Eq>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='TopicID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ProjectID + "</Value>" +
   "</Eq>" +
"</Where>" +
      " <OrderBy>"+
   "<FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' />"+
       "</OrderBy>" ;
```