# Get the value of the first column of the last row from a sharepoint list with PnPPowershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

My SharePoint list contains 4 columns and the first is a date column. The data in the list is sorted ascending. What I would like is to get the value of the first column af the last row of the list. I have this but doesn't give me the last date:

```
Write-Host "my schedule: " (Get-PnPListItem -List "my schedule" | Select-Object -Last 1)["Datum"].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

When I go to the end of my list "My schedule" I see the last date is 31-03-2019
but powershell gives me 30-03-2019 !!!

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the data is sorted ascending, but I'm guessing that it's the view that's sorted. get-pnplistitem isn't retrieving items based on a view, but based on the raw data. But if you check the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps), example #5 has a sample for using a caml query, which would allow you to both sort the data as well as to set a rowlimit. (the example only provides a where statement, but [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/170044/get-the-items-in-descending-order-using-caml-query) is an example of sorting with a caml query, and [here](https://www.sptrenches.com/2016/06/get-all-items-in-5000-large-list-with.html) is an example of rowlimit.

Comment: I think the time is stored as a date/time object, and I have read that it could have one of the 3 properties: UTC, Local, or Unspecified

Comment: I think determine what kind of property is set to the date/time object and declare it in my code. I think that will solve my problem. But I have no idea how to do that. I think the values can be found in the "kind" property

Comment: I have tried: ....["Datum"].ToLocalTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")

Comment: Buit get an error: can not find an overload for "tostring and the argument count: "1"

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. But check your syntax, as you're missing () after the call to ToLocalTime: ToLocalTime().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")